# Discord.py - Bot unable to kick

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I find that I am unable to kick members or other bots using the kick command in my bot. Both I and the bot have administrator permissions. Why could this be happening? I get no compilation errors.

```
@client.command() ##kick
@has_permissions(kick_members = True) # to check the user itself
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    try:
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(+member.mention + " has been sent to the ministry of love for reeducation.")
    except:
        await ctx.send("You cannot!")
```

EDIT: Thanks for the fixes in the comments below. I also came to the realization that I was trying to kick a user of equal level (deprecated bot) and so that also played a part in it not working. I tried to kick a standard user and it worked great!

Comment: Give us more details, please. What happens when you run the code? Does it send "You cannot!"?

Comment: You have an extra "+" in-front `+member.mention`. Don't use bare try-except, this is why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing that the message received from the bot is *"You cannot!"*, the exception thrown is a `TypeError`, and it is handled because you have wrapped it in `try/except`. To make sure, remove the error handling and check your result.

The complete error would look like this: `TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'`.

#### Resources

- [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError)

---

## Bug

In line 6, you have added a bad binary operator `+` in the beginning of argument list, but the operator requires two operands and they are not provided.

```py
await ctx.send(+member.mention + " has been sent to the ministry of love for reeducation.")
```

Hence a `TypeError` is thrown, but it is also handled, so the only result you will see is the "You cannot!" message from the bot.

## Fix

Simply remove the bad operator, and it should be working fine.

```py
await ctx.send(member.mention + " has been sent to the ministry of love for reeducation.")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `@has_permissions(kick_members = True)` line, you have to add `commands`. Here's the fixed command.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    try:
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(+member.mention + " has been sent to the ministry of love for reeducation.")
    except:
        await ctx.send("You cannot!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await member.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f'User {member} has been kicked')
  await member.send(f"You have been kicked from {member.guild.name} | reason: {reason}")

client.run('WRITE YOUR TOKEN HERE')
```

Comment: Try to explain your solution, what all changes you have made, or at least add comments to your code. Posting code like this may not be helpful.